# ¿La propiedad logging.file de Spring Boot es asíncrona?

Tags: spring

De antemano menciono que soy un programador novato en el tema de **Spring**. Intento guardar los **logs** de la aplicación en un archivo, leyendo, **Spring** ofrece la propiedad **loggin.file** donde uno especifica el nombre del archivo o la ruta donde sera creado, mi pregunta es, si esta función es asíncrona o no.
Porque si no *seria necesario crear hilos para la generación del archivo*, a modo que la creación sea asíncrona y no afecte a la aplicación.Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es [CoralLog](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/corallog/). Aunque con [Log4J](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) también lo puedes hacer desde la línea de comando

`-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelecto`r

Con esto habilitas el registro asíncrono.